# How to exclude explicitApi warnings for test classes in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have Android library module with enabled explicitApi kotlin feature in gradle

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += '-Xexplicit-api=warning'
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, but the problem is that warnings are also reported for test classes in packages src/test and src/androidTest.

How to exclude test classes from explicit-api control?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't! I was thinking of opening a bug report just this week but never got to it. In the meantime, I suggest you add something like this to your build script, which will at least fix it for the Kotlin compiler (but you'll still see the IDE warnings):

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile) {
    if (!it.name.contains("Test")) {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xexplicit-api=strict"
    }
}
```

If you're using Gradle Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    if ("UnitTest" !in name) {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xexplicit-api=strict"
    }
}
```

And don't set the compiler argument in `android.kotlinOptions`, only in that block, so that it is applied only to the non-test source sets.

EDIT: I just checked and the warnings bug was fixed in IntelliJ, so it should be fixed in Android Studio in a few months to a year.

Comment: "I just checked and the warnings bug was fixed in IntelliJ" — Any link please?

Comment: I don't think there is any link. I checked in both IDEs at the time and it worked in IntelliJ.